# How do I regenerate designer File in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am getting error as

> The name does not exist in the current path as in issue link [Name does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027025/name-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

I have tried all options in the comments but still unable to find solution,

One comment their says to regenerate designer file by right clicking and selecting **"Convert to Web Application"** but am already using web application and on right click of it am not getting that option. 
Attaching reference Image.
Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a little late to the party here, but I have a solution (and it's as easy as you hoped):

The "Convert To Web Application" menu option was moved to the Project menu item across the top of the Visual Studio 2015 application.

- First, delete the desired designer file.
- Next, click on the ASPX page of the one you want to regenerate the designer for.  If you click on the CS page, the option will not show up in the menu.
- Click on Project from the top menus and you should see "Convert To Web Application" in the menu.  It should be all the way at the bottom of that popup menu.